# PHP - Get Array value by Index instead of Key

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key

I've got a multidimensional array returned by an API call. The values into this array are stored with a key like this :

```
Array(["BTC_XRP"] => 1)
```

I can get the values of the Array by getting them using the keys (like BTC_XRP), but what if I need to get the value using the Index?

For example, how do I get each value of the Array using a for loop if I can't get the values by the Index?

Since the Array is composed by something like 100 values, I need to echo every one using a for loop, but this gives me this error :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Is it possible to get to a value using the Index instead of the Key?

Furthermore, I'd like to get the Key by the Index. If I want to get the Key of the first value, I'd like to get it using the 0 Index.

Comment: use `foreach` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: Have you tried $array[0] where 0 is the number in the array to access it. E.g from your question echo $array[0] should output 1. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @Ashley Prescott Yes that's exactly what I did, but PHP doesn't let you get a value by Index if it's stored as Key.

Comment: **One of those questions with harmfully confused titles**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has a confusing title. What the OP *needed* is simply *how to iterate over associative array*. And the answer is just as silly:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key, value: $value";
}
```

But the title, that attracts people from Google search, explicitly asks how to get a *certain value* from associative array by its *position* (or "index"). For this you need a function called **array_slice()**:

```
$array = array('a'=>'apple', 'b'=>'banana', '42'=>'pear', 'd'=>'orange');

$index = 2;
$elem = array_slice($array, $index, 1, true);
$key = key($elem);
$value = reset($elem);
echo "Key: $key, value: $value"; // Key: 42, value: pear
```

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you are in search of [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) (to get key by index) and [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) (to get value by index) functions:

```
$array = array("BTC_XRP" => 1, "EUR_XRP" => 234, "USD_XRP" => 567);
$keys   = array_keys( $array );
$values = array_values( $array );

var_dump( $keys[1] ); // string(7) "EUR_XRP"
var_dump( $values[1] ); // int(234)
```

Or use a foreach as Joshua suggests.